# Convert latitude and longitude values to radians

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, oracle11g

I've two columns (Oracle) namely latitude and longitude in format I've mentioned below.

Could anyone help me on how to convert them into radians using Oracle/MySQL or Python?

Example: 11.08.10N (Latitude), 084.46.07W (Longitude)

Note:

The latitude of a location is represented by three two-digit numbers separated by periods in the order of degrees,minutes from degrees,seconds from degrees that are followed by a N for north or a S for south.

The longitude of a location is represented by a three digit number and two two-digit numbers separated by periods in the order of degrees,minutes from degrees,seconds from degrees that are followed by a W for west or an E for east

I've seen solutions which they directly convert using radians function like below.

lat = radians(latitude_value)
lon = radians(longitude_value)

This doesn't help me in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use:

```sql
SELECT dms,
       CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(dms, -1, 1) IN ('N', 'E')
       THEN 1
       ELSE -1
       END
       * ( SUBSTR(dms,  1, 3)          -- degrees
         + SUBSTR(dms, -6, 2) /   60   -- minutes
         + SUBSTR(dms, -3, 2) / 3600 ) -- seconds
        AS degrees,
       CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(dms, -1, 1) IN ('N', 'E')
       THEN 1
       ELSE -1
       END
       * ( SUBSTR(dms,  1, 3)          -- degrees
         + SUBSTR(dms, -6, 2) /   60   -- minutes
         + SUBSTR(dms, -3, 2) / 3600 ) -- seconds
       * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 / 180 AS radians
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dms) AS
SELECT '11.08.10N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '084.46.07W' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DMS | DEGREES | RADIANS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11.08.10N | 11.13611111111111111111111111111111111111 | .1943618047568129798301965636353011651234 |
| 084.46.07W | -84.76861111111111111111111111111111111111 | -1.47949136623153770555853316874267774151 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xKpSke2i)

Comment: Thanks @MT0, Only one change identified in above SQL that for latitude we should fetch only 2 bytes. i.e. SUBSTR(dms,  1, 2) for degrees field.

Comment: @sandy No, for longitude you want 3 digits and for latitude you want 2 digits and the 3rd digit will be a decimal point so you can quite happily take 3 digits for both (which simplifies everything as you do not need to have different functions for each). You can see it working in the answer for both longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 0):

It's just basic string manipulation and math.  In mysql, for latitude:

```
radians((substring_index(lat,'.',1)
    +substring_index(substring_index(lat,'.',2),'.',-1)/60
    +trim(trailing 'N' from trim(trailing 'S' from substring_index(lat,'.',-1)))/3600
)*(case substr(lat from -1) when 'S' then -1 else 1 end))
```

Similarly, for longitude:

```
radians((substring_index(lon,'.',1)
    +substring_index(substring_index(lon,'.',2),'.',-1)/60
    +trim(trailing 'E' from trim(trailing 'W' from substring_index(lon,'.',-1)))/3600
)*(case substr(lon from -1) when 'W' then -1 else 1 end))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l30wRnJs)