# PostgreSQL - Convert Latitude and Longitude to radians

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pyspark

I am working on converting lats and logs to radians and I've two columns (PostgreSQL) namely latitude and longitude in format I've mentioned below.

Could anyone help me on how to convert them into radians using PostgreSQL, Pyspark or Python?

Example: 11.08.10N (Latitude), 084.46.07W (Longitude)

Note:

The latitude of a location is represented by three two-digit numbers separated by periods in the order of degrees,minutes from degrees,seconds from degrees that are followed by a N for north or a S for south.

The longitude of a location is represented by a three digit number and two two-digit numbers separated by periods in the order of degrees,minutes from degrees,seconds from degrees that are followed by a W for west or an E for east

I've seen solutions which they directly convert using radians function like below.

lat = radians(latitude_value) lon = radians(longitude_value)

This doesn't help me in my scenario.

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of your previous question, [Latitude and Longitude to rads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778945/latitude-and-longitude-to-rads). Please edit that one instead if you have further details or are not satisfied with the answers.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, my previous question was answered for Oracle, but I need to find solution for the same in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ah, I've reverted your edit that put new tags on the other question. Still, you might want to have included a link to the older question and explain how exactly it was different. Also, the Oracle answer seems to use rather standard SQL features, did you try to use that for Postgres as well? If so, how did it not work?

Comment: Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: text / integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 934
SQLState:  42883
ErrorCode: 0

Comment: This is the error I am seeing, seems like getting this error when we tried to multiply int with varchar.

Comment: Ah, well you'll need to cast that `text` to `int` (or rather, `numeric`) before doing arithmetic with it

Comment: for pyspark, see [`radians`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.radians.html#pyspark-sql-functions-radians)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dms,
       CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(dms, -1, 1) IN ('N', 'E')
       THEN 1
       ELSE -1
       END
       * ( SUBSTR(dms,  1, 3) ::numeric          -- degrees
         + SUBSTR(dms, -6, 2) ::numeric  /   60   -- minutes
         + SUBSTR(dms, -3, 2) ::numeric / 3600 ) -- seconds
        AS degrees,
       CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(dms, -1, 1) IN ('N', 'E')
       THEN 1
       ELSE -1
       END
       * ( SUBSTR(dms,  1, 3) ::numeric           -- degrees
         + SUBSTR(dms, -6, 2) ::numeric  /   60   -- minutes
         + SUBSTR(dms, -3, 2) ::numeric  / 3600 ) -- seconds
       * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 / 180 AS radians
FROM   table_name;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).